# Batch renaming on OS X terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, batch-rename

I have files with the following names:

```
01 011.mp3
01 022.mp3
01 033.mp3
```

What code should I run on terminal (OS X) to make them look like this:

```
011.mp3
022.mp3
033.mp3
```

Comment: Okay, what have you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would achieve this is using a simple Bash for-loop with a glob of the mp3s you are interested in.  Using `*\ *.mp3` should give you anything containing at least one space.  Then using `sed` to remove all characters up to and including the first space, will give the target file name.  Finally, giving the source and target name to `mv`, and aborting on error.

```
for f in *\ *.mp3; do
    t=$(sed -e 's/^.* //' <<< "$f")
    mv -v "$f" "$t" || break
done
```

This can all be done in one line:

```
for f in *\ *.mp3; do t=$(sed -e 's/^.* //' <<< "$f"); mv -v "$f" "$t" || break; done
```

As with any bash code affecting your files, it always pays to do a *dry run* first, by prefixing `mv` with `echo` and escaping the quotes.  *i.e.*

```
echo mv -v \"$f\" \"$t\"
```

That way you'll see what the script is going to do before you run it for real.

---

A nicer alternative provided by Steve Vinoski in the comments removes the need for `sed`:

```
for f in *\ *.mp3; do mv -v "$f" "${f##* }" || break; done
```

Comment: No need for `sed`; instead, you can drop everything in `f` before the space using this [bash construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): `${f##* }`. It means "strip the largest left part of `$f` that matches the pattern `* ` (which is a '*' followed by a space) and return what's left." So you just need `mv -v "$f" "${f##* }" || break` inside the loop.

Comment: Ooh nice one.  Thanks.  I will have a quick blat with that and edit the alternative in.

Comment: OP didn't say what shell he was using but if using `zsh` with `zmv` you can do something like this `zmv  '01 (*).mp3' '$1.mp3'`

Comment: @Doon Mac OS X terminal uses Bash by default, so I assumed Bash.  Thanks for the `zsh` alternative though.

Comment: Yep, bash be a good assumption. Just pointing out quick/ easy way to rename with zmv. It is really quite powerful.